# Lambda Script to get instances name which are not having a particular tag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

For test purpose i am having 3 instances , 2 have tag in them key:Backup Value:Testing and 1 is without this i want to get the instance name which is not having this particular tag. I am trying this logic that i am getting all the instance name and then finding which instances having this backup tag and then removing the 2nd list from 1st. i am able to get both the list but not able to filter out the 2nd list from the first.

Code:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:

            print(instance["InstanceId"])


    tags_NV = ec2.describe_tags(
    Filters = [
        {
            'Name':'resource-type',
            'Values':['instance']
        },
        {
        'Name':'key',
        'Values':['Backup']
        }
    ]
    )

    ami_backuppolicy = {i['ResourceId'] for i in tags_NV['Tags']}
    print(ami_backuppolicy)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: c271c3b3-9c64-4d7b-829f-d34ffcb5e944 Version: $LATEST

i-05a448daa5823d6af
i-0f79ec69714932e8e
i-058bfa970112e8565

{'i-058bfa970112e8565', 'i-05a448daa5823d6af'}

END RequestId: c271c3b3-9c64-4d7b-829f-d34ffcb5e944
REPORT RequestId: c271c3b3-9c64-4d7b-829f-d34ffcb5e944  Duration: 480.40 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB  Init Duration: 276.17 ms
```

Comment: what is the output of `tags_NV1` and `tags_NV`?

Comment: @Marcin the ami_backuppolicy list out all the instance having the tag and above it all the instance id is printed , how can i find 1st - 2nd

Comment: What do you mean by "Instance Name"? Do you mean the instance ID, or the value of the `Name` tag?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i meant instance ID only

Comment: @JohnRotenstein used your code and mixed with mine to get the result. All instanceId were 3 , instance having backup tag were 2 . so i took out the difference of both the list . Thankyou for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an AWS Lambda function that will find any instances that do not have the given tag:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

    not_backed_up = []

    for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
        if not [tag for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Backup' and tag['Value'] == 'Testing']:
            not_backed_up.append(instance.id)

    print(not_backed_up)
```

Comment: the code you provided only lists out the instance id having the backup tag, that is 2 in my case. i tried this code and the output was 2 instance id that were having the tag. But your idea helped me , thanks a ton

Comment: Oops! Fixed it by inserting a `not`.

Comment: can you suggest me from where i can learn aws lambda scripting like i know python so i was able to crack the logic of taking difference of 2 lists but i do not know how to write efficiently the aws part logic

Comment: I find that reading the [EC2 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) and doing web searches for sample code is a fine way to learn things! Learning from other people's code is very useful. I just did a search on YouTube for "boto3 python" and there are lots of videos. Real programmers never re-invent stuff that has already been written.

Answer (score 0):

CODE :

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    list=[]
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    response = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:

            list.append(instance["InstanceId"])

    not_backed_up = []
    list_difference = []
    for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
        if [tag for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Backup' and tag['Value'] == 'Testing']:
            not_backed_up.append(instance.id)

    print(list)
    print(not_backed_up)

    for item in list:
        if item not in not_backed_up:
         list_difference.append(item)

    print(list_difference)
```

OUTPUT :

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 73fcb1b0-5421-47dc-88f6-b82f581aa461 Version: $LATEST

['i-05a448daa5823d6af', 'i-0f79ec69714932e8e', 'i-058bfa970112e8565']

['i-05a448daa5823d6af', 'i-058bfa970112e8565']

['i-0f79ec69714932e8e']

The 3rd output is the instance not having the backup tag